# MKMapView:didUpdateUserLocation vs CLLocationManager:didUpdateLocations

Tags: ios, geolocation

I've written my app with CLLocationManager:didUpdateLocations and have user options to choose between SignificantLocationChanges or timed updates. But I see that showing the user's location causes a constant updating that passes lat and long into didUpdateUserLocation. Does "mapView.showsUserLocation" make a complete waste of my other code that uses SignificantLocationChanges or timed intervals? I'm thinking it has to if it's getting such frequent readings. Is the solution for me to show my own blue annotation for the user?